# Is it a general structure?

Tags: grammar

> He was not the only one to call for a legal reform in the sixteenth century.

In this sentence I expect to see "who" instead of "to":

> He was not the only who called for a legal reform in the sixteenth century.

I wonder is the first sentence following a general grammatical structure?

Comment: It's certainly not uncommon. See [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+only+one+to%2Cthe+only+one+who%2Cnot+the+only+one+who%2Cnot+the+only+one+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20only%20one%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20only%20one%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20the%20only%20one%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20the%20only%20one%20to%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @muru Thanks for your comment. I'm looking for some explanation